# The Lie subgroup corresponding to inner derivations

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional real or complex Lie algebra. We know that $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ is a closed real or complex Lie subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{g})$. We also know that the Lie algebra of the former is $Der(\mathfrak{g}) \subseteq \mathfrak{gl(g)}$. We have the adjoint representation $ad \colon \mathfrak{g} \to Der(\mathfrak{g})$, whose image is the ideal of inner derivations $Inn(\mathfrak{g}) \trianglelefteq Der(\mathfrak{g})$. Therefore, there is a unique connected Lie subgroup $H$ of $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ whose Lie algebra is $Inn(\mathfrak{g})$, and this subgroup is in fact normal. Do we have some explicit description of $H$?

I have come up with one, but it is not so constructive. Let $G$ be the unique simply connected real or complex Lie group whose Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$. We have a morphism of groups $C \colon G \to Aut(G)$, whose image is the normal subgroup of inner automorphisms $Inn(G) \trianglelefteq Aut(G)$. Moreover, we have an isomorphism of groups $Aut(G) \cong Aut(\mathfrak{g}), F \mapsto F_*$. When we identify these groups via this isomorphism, $C$ becomes $Ad \colon G \to Aut(\mathfrak{g})$, which we know is a morphism of Lie groups. Finally, we know that $Ad_* = ad$. This implies that our H is actually nothing but the image of $G$ under $Ad$ (it is reasonable to continue denoting it by $Inn(G)$). But this description is not in terms of $\mathfrak{g}$, so I wonder if there is something more practical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "practical": the subgroup induced by inner automorphisms is a quite natural answer. Maybe more practically, you can view it as the subgroup generated by the exponentials $\exp(\mathrm{ad}(x))$, when $x$ ranges over $\mathfrak{g}$. Here $\exp$ is the matrix exponential of $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: @YCor, yes, maybe the exp description is the best one can come up with, at least it doesn't involve any additional Lie group. My initial hope was to find some description of the sort “an automorphism F of $\mathfrak{g}$ lies in $H$ if and only if its action on $\mathfrak{g}$ satisfies some propetry X”, where X may be about its interaction with the Killing form or something like this. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, for instance for a nilpotent Lie algebra the Killing form is zero, so will not help much.